# Android telephony.getLine1Number() outputs inconsistent(?) phone numbers

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I have Android app which uses Android  `telephony.getLine1Number()` to output device phone. It worked well until someone with `msg.fi.google.com` provider started using it.
Apparently, `msg.fi.google.com` makes Android output phone number with **"+1"** prefix.
Is it normal behavior or bug? Did anyone experience it? Should we add code layer to deal with this issue?
Please let us know, since Google Search yields nothing